# How to run multiple terminal sessions (Tabs) in pydroid 3

Tags: python, django, terminal, tabs, pydroid

I am trying to create an app using pydroid 3.
When I view if the project is setup properly with python manage.py runserver
Everything is set up ok but when it's time to start the app,
I have to open another terminal or tab while the terminal with runserver continues running.
How do I open another terminal session(or tab) without closing runserver.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use two terminal tabs at same time in pydroid3 but you can use termux to run server file by installing python3  in termux on your mobile.